# In Snowflake how to find smallest value for each row from 'N' number of columns without including NULL values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, min

I have table with columns like Col1, Col2, Col3... ColN

The table value is something like this

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NULL | 500 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 15 | 1 | 400 | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 20 | 2 | NULL | 10 | 2 |

I tried

`SMALLEST(VAL1,VAL2, VAL3... VALN)`

But it returns NULL value. I want to ignore NULL Values and compare non-null values.

Please help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact.html) to remove NULL values:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, t.Col4, MIN(value) AS least
FROM tab AS t
, TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT(t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, t.Col4)))
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3, t.Col4
ORDER BY t.ID;
```

Sample input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Tab(ID INT, COL1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT, Col4 INT)
AS
SELECT 1,10,NULL,500,5 UNION
SELECT 2,15,1,400,NULL UNION
SELECT 3,20,2,NULL,10;
```

Output:

[image]

---

EDIT: Using `ARRAY_MIN`:

```
WITH cte(ID , COL1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4 ) AS (
  SELECT 1,10,NULL,500,5 UNION
  SELECT 2,15,1,400,NULL UNION
  SELECT 3,20,2,NULL,10
)
SELECT *, ARRAY_MIN([COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4])
FROM cte;
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks a lot for your inputs!   :) When I use some varchar filed it is giving the expected answers. But with "". Is there any way to get ride of that?   AAA   BBB  CCC  => "AAA"

Comment: @jeenap This should be a completely new question. For handling VARCHAR
instead of `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT(t.Col1, ...)))` you could use `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT(NULLIF(TRIM(t.Col1),''), ...)))`

Answer (score 0):

Check out LEAST: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html

Unfortunately, by default LEAST is considering NULL as well. To avoid this, you can apply a COALESCE for each parameter containing all other columns you would like to check. This doesn’t look super pretty but should work:

```
LEAST(COALESCE(col1,col2,col3), COALESCE(col2,col1,col3), COALESCE(col3, col1, col2))
```

Only if all columns are null the output is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs! :) Hope this will not work when we have 'N' number of columns

Comment: No, this would not work until you make it dynamic.